# how to hide the sidebar on saleorder formview odoo?

Tags: odoo, sidebar, odoo-12, qweb

I have been trying many different ways for hiding the sidebar button. Below code is working on all forms. However, i just want to hide it on sale order form. Widget.modelName seems not working because it is before the form declaration. I also tried   doc_model in [sale.order'] and not working as well. How can I solve it? thanks

```
        <t t-jquery = ".o_cp_left" t-operation = "replace">

          <t t-if = "widget.modelName == 'sale.order'">

              <div class="o_cp_left hiddenManagerSO">

                  <div class="o_cp_buttons" role="toolbar" aria-label="Control panel toolbar"/>

                  <aside class="o_cp_sidebar"/>

              </div>

          </t>

          <t t-if = "widget.modelName !== 'sale.order'">

              <div class="o_cp_left hiddenManagerKOO">

                  <div class="o_cp_buttons" role="toolbar" aria-label="Control panel toolbar"/>

                  <aside class="o_cp_sidebar"/>

              </div>

          </t>

        </t>

</t>
```

Comment: You can check the code of some apps which is providing slider of side bar. That might be helpful.

Comment: thanks for your response. However, i think you are talking about the web module. I am talking about the backend module like sale order, po, mrp and so on.